# How do I make it so when everytime I call a function in the Command Prompt I don't need to open the file again?

Tags: python

Good day people, I want to make a simple dice roll app in which when you press Enter it will print a dice face. My question is: how can I make it so I don't need to open the file again (python dice_roll.py)? I'm a beginner so please don't bully me. Thanks.

```
import random

def dice1():
    print("_________")
    print("|       |")
    print("|   x   |")
    print("|       |")
    print("|_______|")

def dice2():

    print("_________")
    print("| x     |")
    print("|       |")
    print("|     x |")
    print("|_______|")

def dice3():

    print("_________")
    print("| x     |")
    print("|   x   |")
    print("|     x |")
    print("|_______|")

def dice4():

    print("_________")
    print("| x   x |")
    print("|       |")
    print("| x   x |")
    print("|_______|")

def dice5():

    print("_________")
    print("| x   x |")
    print("|   x   |")
    print("| x   x |")
    print("|_______|")

def dice6():

    print("_________")
    print("| x   x |")
    print("| x   x |")
    print("| x   x |")
    print("|_______|")

dice_list = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6]

def roll_dice():
    random.choice(dice_list)()

enter = input("Press Enter to roll the dice")

if enter == "":
    roll_dice()
```

Comment: Do you want the program to keep running until the user presses another key?

Comment: Nope, I want it so the user only needs to load the program once and to generate new dices the user only needs to press Enter.

Comment: What you want is called an "event loop" or sometimes the "main loop"

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap three lines around a while-loop!

To terminate, just press `CTRL-C` in the terminal. Or alternatively, you could also specify a condition, such as when "q" is entered, then `break` out of the loop:

```
while True:
    enter = input("Press Enter to roll the dice").lower()

    if enter == "q":
        break
    else:
        roll_dice()
```

Comment: Won't work.  `.lower()` will make any entry lowercase and so will never match `Q`  Fix your code.  Did you even run this code?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to wrap the main logic inside an infinite loop, and break from it when the user enters a specific word, e.g.

Replace this code:

```
enter = input("Press Enter to roll the dice")

if enter == "":
    roll_dice()
```

With this:

```
while True:
    enter = input("Press Enter to roll the dice, or exit to terminate")

    if enter == "exit":
        break

    if enter == "":
        roll_dice()
```

This means:

- repeat indefinitely
- when the user enters "exit", break from the loop
- when the user just presses the *enter* key, roll the dice